# How to install .cod file of blackberry in blackberry device

Tags: blackberry

I want to tell my blackberry app in blackberry device. I searched and found that you have to place .cod, .jad and .alx file and then download and install the .jad file in the device. I did this but it said Class net.rim.device.api.command.Command not found.

I think I have to add more files or what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to do load ur project into devive?

Comment: Yes, I wwant to install/load my app into the device

Comment: have signed ur app with blackberry signing keys?

Comment: I clicked on Install New Keys in the Prefereces. It asks me to upload a key from a file. But I don't have that. How can I install a new key then?

Comment: fillup this form u will get keys from bb  "  https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html  "

Comment: Done, what should I do after this now?

Comment: have u imported those three keys to ur eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created this cod file , than before installing it on Blackberry Device you need to Signed it first.
 See this video how to sign .

```
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Deploying-and-Signing-Applications-in-the-BlackBerry-JDE-Plug-in/ta-p/446877
```

Once you sign your cod file , you can install it on BB phone by .COD file or by .JAD file.

If you want to install using .JAD file , copy your .COD file into SDCARD & .JAD too. Remember if you have more than 60KB .COD file size than you need to extract it to divide into 60KB Sizes(Use 7  Zip to extract) & put in same folder as in .jad File & open .Jad file from Phone & Follow the icstruction.

If you want to install by .COD File , than you may have used BB Eclipse Env. 
GOTO

```
<installed Eclipse folder>/plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack<SDK Ver>\components\bin
```

& paste your cod file in bin folder. Now open COmmand prompt point to this folder & use this command before it connect your BB Phone by USB to computer

```
JavaLoader load <cod file name>
```

Follow this link for more guidance

```
 http://www.bbgeeks.com/blackberry-guides/blackberry-guide-how-to-install-third-party-applications-onto-your-blackberry-88400/
```

Answer (score 1):

cod files with alx file are for desktop installation via usb-cable. Launch BB Desktop Manager, specify alx file and BB Desktop Manager will install cod files (described in alx-file) to the connected device.

cod files and jad file are for wireless installation. Device opens jad file in browser, and downloads and installs all cod files described in jad file.

That's it.